# JFrame not displaying output?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, awt

I am new to Java, and the whole working with arrays + using classes and their methods to populate and display the arrays. I have spent the last 2-3 hours, working on this and checking google for various answers and none have seemed to help, I am still stuck. I don't really know how to use the methods from the rectangle1 class, when using arrays.

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GameBoard frame = new GameBoard();
}
```

GameBoard Class

```
public class GameBoard extends JFrame {

    public GameBoard() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 195, 215);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Rectangle1 board[][] = new Rectangle1[3][3];
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                board[row][col] = new Rectangle1(0, 0, 195, 215);
                if ((row + col) % 2 == 0) {
                    Graphics g = null;    
                    board[row][col].paint(g);
                    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, 195, 215);
                } else {
                    Graphics h = null;
                    board[row][col].paint(h);
                    h.setColor(Color.red);
                    h.fillRect(0, 0, 195, 215);
                }
                frame.add(board[row][col]);
            }    
        }  

    }
}
```

Rectangle1 class.

```
public class Rectangle1 extends JComponent  {

    /** post:   getX() == x  and  getY() == y
     *          and  getWidth() == w  and getHeight() == h
     *          and  getBackground() == Color.black
     */
    public Rectangle1(int x, int y, int w, int h)  {
        super();
        setBounds(x, y, w, h);
        setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    /** post:   this method draws a filled Rectangle
     *          and  the upper left corner is (getX(), getY()) 
     *          and  the rectangle's dimensions are getWidth() and getHeight()
     *          and  the rectangle's color is getBackground()
     */
    public void paint(Graphics g)  {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
        paintChildren(g);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are fighting the layout manager, calling something like `setBounds(x, y, w, h)` in you `Rectangle` class is going to overridden by the layout manager of the parent container (the frame in this case)

Secondly, you are not responsible for painting, do this;

```
board[row][col].paint(g);
g.setColor(Color.yellow);
g.fillRect(0, 0, 195, 215);
```

...is wrong.  If it doesn't end up with you programming crashing, then your lucky.

While I try and figure out a solution, you might like to take some time and read through

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

While on my rant...

This;
    public void paint(Graphics g)  {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
        paintChildren(g);
    }

is inappropriate.  You MUST call `super.paint()`, there's to much going on in the background for you to override this method without calling it's `super`.

In fact, you should avoid overriding `paint` where ever possible and user `paintComponent` instead.

Also, coordinates in Swing are relative to the component.  That is, the top/left corner of any component (within the context of the component) is always 0x0

Here's a working example

```
public class TestBoard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestBoard();
    }

    public TestBoard() {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                new GameBoard();

            }
        });

    }

    public class GameBoard extends JFrame {

        public GameBoard() {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            Rectangle1 board[][] = new Rectangle1[3][3];
            for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {

                gbc.gridx = 0;

                for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                    board[row][col] = new Rectangle1(195, 215);
                    if ((row + col) % 2 == 0) {
                        board[row][col].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    } else {
                        board[row][col].setBackground(Color.RED);
                    }
                    frame.add(board[row][col], gbc);
                    gbc.gridx++;
                }

                gbc.gridy++;

            }

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    }

    public class Rectangle1 extends JPanel {

        public Rectangle1(int w, int h) {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        }

    }
}
```

Because of the nature of your requirements, I've been forced to use `GridBagLayout` which is not the simplest of layout managers to use.

`JComponents` are transparent by nature and you are required to fill them, better to use `JPanel`

Answer (score 1):

Comments:

1. `GameBoard` extends `JFrame` but then you create a `JFrame` instance in the `GameBoard` constructor. You should do one or the other, but not both.
2. `Rectangle.paint()` should probably be `Rectangle.paintComponent()`. Now you just have to create Rectangle objects and add them to a container, such as a `JFrame` or a `JPanel`. They will be painted automatically. You don't have to call `paint()` or `paintComponent()` explicitly if you are extending `JComponent`.

Comment: For point 1. Just use an instance of a frame, unless adding new behavior (very rare).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tend to extend JFrame and add components in the constructor. Of course, that is usually only a single custom JPanel which then adds components in *its* constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `null` Graphics object to paint your window. Instead of using

```
Graphics g = null; Graphics h = null;
```

Use

```
Graphics g = getGraphics(); Graphics h = getGraphics();
```

Most probably this would have given you a `NullPointerException` isn't it?

And more over since your rectangles are inheriting from the `JComponent`, you should not call `paint()` method yourself. Instead call `repaint()` once all of them are added to the frame.

Comment: I was getting that before.

I made those changes and still get:



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at tictactoe.Rectangle1.paint(Rectangle1.java:28)
 at tictactoe.GameBoard.<init>(GameBoard.java:32)
 at tictactoe.TicTacToe.main(TicTacToe.java:22)

Comment: Instead of calling the `paint()` method, call `repaint()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
Graphics g = null;
board[row][col].paint(g);
```

You calling paint() with a null Graphics which causes a `NullPointerException`

```
public void paint(Graphics g)  {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
        paintChildren(g);
}
```

Comment: For clarification, this is one of several issues.